# Redefining LoF, LoT formatting without affecting their respective ToC entries?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I am trying to centre my ToC, LoF and LoT headings in small caps. I've managed to change the ToC, LoF and LoT to small caps, but I have 2 problems:

1. The LoF and LoT entries are not able to be centered
2. The ToC entries too adopt the capitalisation and centering formatting.

How can I fix these please?

In short: (a) the LoF and LoT headings need to be centered (like the ToC) in small caps but (b) appear in normal text in the ToC entries.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}{\centering\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\textsc{table\enspace of\enspace contents}}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\hspace*{\fill}\textsc{list of figures}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\hspace*{\fill}\textsc{list of tables}}

    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables

\section{Test}

\begin{figure}[H]
   \includegraphics[width=1cm]{c:/temp/Final_images/va_blacked.png}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}{\centering\Huge\scshape\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\printloftitle}{\centering\Huge\scshape\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\printlottitle}{\centering\Huge\scshape\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{table of contents}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{list of figures}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{list of tables}

    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables

\chapter{chapter title}
\section{section title}

\begin{figure}[p]
  \caption{figure caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[p]
  \caption{table caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you. Would you know how to make the ToC entries for "List of figures" and "List of Tables" in lower case text (while remaining in SC in their header locations)?

Comment: Every font macro like \textsc{...} has a corresponding switch form like \scshape.