# Adding table headers to table of contents, list of figures and list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing a book with prerequired specified formats. 
It's required to have the table of contents with table headers as shown: 
[image: I'd like to add this "page" header next to toc]

I'd like to add this "Page" header next to "Table of Contents"
Also I need to apply the same for list of figures and list of tables : 
[image]

[image]

In brief, I want these stuff to be typed as a real borderless table

This is my sample:

```
\documentclass[14pt,fleqn]{extbook} % Default font size and left-justified equations

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself
\listoffigures

\chapter{title1}
\section{subtitle1}
\section{subtitle2}
\section{subtitle3}

\chapter{title2}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{photo.jpg}
  \caption{what a beautiful flower}
\end{figure}

\chapter{title3}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{photo.jpg}
  \caption{the same flower}
\end{figure}

\chapter{title4}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{photo.jpg}
  \caption{the same flower again}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Other document classes do some of this automatically.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387913/redefining-lof-lot-formatting-without-affecting-their-respective-toc-entries/387935#387935 for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solves most of the problem.  You can adjust the indentation using tocloft or modifying `\l@chapter` etc. directly.

Unfortunately, the easy way to center/reformat the titles for `\tableofcontents` and `\listoffigures` also messes up the page headers.

```
\documentclass[14pt,fleqn]{extbook} % Default font size and left-justified equations 

\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\large\hfill Table of Contents\hfill\llap{Page}}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\normalsize\underline{Figure No.}\hfill
  \underline{Caption}\hfill
  \underline{Page}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Table of Contents}%
\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself
\cleardoublepage% move to first page ot LOF
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{List of Figures}%
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{headings}%
\chapter{title1}
\section{subtitle1}
\section{subtitle2}
\section{subtitle3}

\chapter{title2}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  %\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{photo.jpg}
  \caption{what a beautiful flower}
\end{figure}

\chapter{title3}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  %\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{photo.jpg}
  \caption{the same flower}
\end{figure}

\chapter{title4}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  %\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{photo.jpg}
  \caption{the same flower again}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```